# In C, how to 're-initialize' a single variable and use it on each iteration of a while loop?

Tags: c, string, parsing, while-loop

Basically, I'm trying to find the averages of all the numbers in each line of a file I'm parsing. I'm pretty close to figuring out a solution. I manage to read all the numbers successfully, and the "adding" works fine on the first iteration, but after the first iteration, the numbers are added to the sum of the previous iteration. Is there a way to simply reuse the same variable, print its value after one iteration, then initialize it to 0 and use it again in the next iteration, etc.? Here's a sample of what I'd like to get at (in pseudo code, I'm not asking for this to print to the console):

```
1,2,3,4,5
x = 1;
x = 3;
x = 6;
x = 10;
x = 15;
15
2,3,4,5
x = 2;
x = 5;
x = 9;
x = 14;
14
etc.
```

Here's the code I have right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int  i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    char *token;
    char line[300];
    char s[2] = ",";
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while(fgets(line, 299, fp)){
        token = strtok(line, s);
        while(token!=NULL){
        x = x + atoi(token);
        printf("%s\n", token);
        printf("%d\n", x);
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }

    }
```

I know I'm close, just need a bit of a tip. I'm not asking for you to copy and paste a solution, but rather give me a tip to help me work through it. Thanks.

Comment: Set `x = 0` right before the inner `while` instead of earlier on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add x = 0 before or after the inner loop

```
while(fgets(line, 299, fp)){
   token = strtok(line, s);
   while(token!=NULL){
        x = x + atoi(token);
        printf("%s\n", token);
        printf("%d\n", x);
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
    x=0;
}
```

Comment: Wow. this works. Can't believe I didn't think of this already. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, you were extremely close just missed one line